# CSV values to compare with table values

Tags: java, database, dictionary, compare

Need to compare CSV data with table rows data

Have tried map for csv and array for table query

Comment: Details under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56330004/compare-columns-in-csv-with-columns-in-database-table-in-java

Comment: Please help ...

Answer (score 0):

I hope it will help you:

```
public List<String[]> readCSV(String csvFile) throws IOException {
    List<String[]> returnVal = new ArrayList<>();
    String line;
    try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(csvFile))) {
       while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
           returnVal.add(line.split(","));
    }
    return returnVal;
}
```

This function take csv file(path) and return list of rows.

You can compare the rows or do any analysis on the data.